# Coding assignment Pseudocode

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

here is a open ended question , Given an event that is fired only once and multiple threads can register callbacks, all to be fired after the event occurs,note the callbacks trying to register after the event has to fire immediately. How to prevent race conditions/all callbacks called properly. What do you guys think ?

```
Register(func){

  if(flag == true){
       call func;
  }

  mutex lock

  push  the callbacks in queue

  mutex un_lock

}

even_fired(){

   mutex lock

   execute the function in the queue
   notify flag
   mutex un_lock
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fired only once"? Once per running the software? Once per reset of the environment? Once absolutely ever? When is the event considered consumed? Consider the event fired and all registered functions have already been called. Then years later (or say 90% of the estimated uptime, whatever it is) a new function gets registered. Should it be called?

Comment: Hi Yunnosch,  1] It's Once absolutely ever 2] The event is consumed when it is fired I am assuming when some variable is set to indicate the event happened. 3] Yes the new function has to be called years later as well.

Comment: So if the system is switched off and on again later you still want the received event to be present and any function registering for it be executed immediatly. For that you need non-volatile memory to store the fact that the event has occured across e.g. removing the battery and reinstalling a new one.

Comment: If the event still has an effecot on newly registered functions i would not consider it consumed. But that is a matter of opinion I think...

Comment: What I try to illustrate with this nitpicking is that you need to give more context information. Also maybe it is time to take one step back and consider whether this might be a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch, It's not so complicated the timeline is for a short time and the professor wants to see how we use lock. I totally understand it's confusing . So basically  event can be fired anytime  let's take a timeline of 10min , 1]  2  threads come in at 5min to register  callbacks 2]At 6 min  event fires 3] let's say at 6 min the one thread come to register . How would we protect it. ?

Comment: What is wrong in protecting the **whole code** of the `Register` function with the mutex? So the flag will be checked under the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
  if(flag == true){
       call func;
  }
  <<< what happens if the event fires here? >>>
  mutex lock 
  push  the callbacks in queue
  mutex un_lock
...
```

To solve these sorts of problems, you have to look at every point in time where the event could occur, and determine if your mechanism would handle it.   An important characteristic of "every point in time", is that statements even in languages like C are not necessarily atomic; the code:

```
if (flag == true) {
```

might become:

```
   load flag, %r0
   cmp  $0, %r0
   je   1f
```

So the event_fired() can happen between the load and cmp instruction, which will also cause your callback to be missed.  In application-oriented languages the discrepancy becomes wider.  You need to explicitly remove the race condition with respect to the language you are using.